# Red-Hat Cluster doesnt migrate services on node shutdown

Tags: linux, redhat, cluster, high-availability, rhcs

I have a RHCS with two nodes and manual fencing. when I restart Node 1 (the primary) it migrates both services to Node 2 automatically.
but when I shutdown Node 1, it doesnt happen and I need to use fence_ack_manual to fence Node 1 and then services are migrated to Node 2.

why does this happens?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Cluster fencing is importan component, so if the fencing request doesn't goes, the cluster stop every operation until the cluster is in clean stay, manual fencing is fake fencing